# Validate a base64 decoded image in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, data-uri

Im trying to get a image from a PUT request for update a user picture(using postman), and make it pass through a validation in Laravel 5.2, for making the call in postman use the following url:

http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users?_method=PUT

and send the image string in the body, using a json like this:

```
{
    "picture" : "data:image/png;base64,this-is-the-base64-encode-string"
}
```

In the controller try a lot of differents ways for decode the image and try to pass the validation:

1. First I tried this:

   ```
   $data = request->input('picture');
   $data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);
   $data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
   $image = base64_decode($data);
   $file = app_path() . uniqid() . '.png';
   $success = file_put_contents($file, $image);
   ```
2. Then I tried this:

   ```
   list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
   list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
   $data = base64_decode($data);
   $typeFile = explode(':', $type);
   $extension = explode('/', $typeFile[1]);
   $ext = $extension[1];
   Storage::put(public_path() . '/prueba.' . $ext, $data);
   $contents = Storage::get(base_path() . '/public/prueba.png');
   ```
3. Try to use the intervention image  library (http://image.intervention.io/) and don't pass:

   ```
   $image = Image::make($data);
   $image->save(app_path() . 'test2.png');
   $image = Image::make(app_path() . 'test1.png');
   ```

This is the validation in the controller:

```
    $data = [
        'picture' => $image,
        'first_name' => $request->input('first_name'),
        'last_name' => $request->input('last_name')
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, User::rulesForUpdate());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->respondFailedParametersValidation('Parameters failed validation for a user picture');
    }
```

this is the validation in the User-model:

```
public static function rulesForUpdate() {
    return [
        'first_name' => 'max:255',
        'last_name' => 'max:255',
        'picture' => 'image|max:5000|mimes:jpeg,png'
    ];
}
```

Comment: I'm not following. What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: Cant pass the validation for a image created from a base64 string

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can extend the Validator class of Laravel.

[Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

But anyway try this

```
Validator::extend('is_png',function($attribute, $value, $params, $validator) {
    $image = base64_decode($value);
    $f = finfo_open();
    $result = finfo_buffer($f, $image, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    return $result == 'image/png';
});
```

Don't forget the rules:

```
$rules = array(
   'image' => 'is_png'
);
```

Comment: if the hacker put a string start with "/9j" (e.g: "/9j{{what_ever_additional_string_to_hack_here}}") in the input, it is still detect as `image/jpeg` .... so this validation is not secured

Comment: the $result variable return "application/octet-stream" instead of "image/png" or "image/jpg"

Comment: Any way to validate the dimensions of the image?

Answer (score 31):

If you are using Intervention anyways, then you can leverage it for a custom validation rule.  I have one called "imageable".  It basically makes sure that the input given will be able to be converted to an Intervention image.  Base64 data image strings will pass.  A string of "foo" will not.

```
Validator::extend('imageable', function ($attribute, $value, $params, $validator) {
    try {
        ImageManagerStatic::make($value);
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

This obviously just checks that the input is able to be converted to an image.  However, it should show you as a use-case how you can leverage Intervention and any of it's methods to create a custom rule.

Comment: I have added your code in the ```boot``` method of the ```AppServiceProvider```. But the base64 string doesn't pass the validation. Am I missing something? Where the extension is defined?

Comment: @JCarlos I place mine in the `boot` method as well.  You must have something else wrong.

Comment: This really helped me out in my current app, thanks a million!!

Comment: Dont forget to import use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic;

Answer (score 0):

inside extend function add this

```
$res= mime_content_type($value);
if ($res == 'image/png' || $res == 'image/jpeg') {
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: This only works if you upload a real file and not a data url or data base64

Comment: this work if you pass a base64 I tried it many times plz give it a try

Comment: yes this code will work