# How to Validate images with validator in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have some struggles with image validation with Laravel.

I'm sending data from vue.js, and json looks like:

```
images: [
   "data:image/png;base64, codehere",
    "data:image/png;base64, codehere",
]
```

And my validator looks like:

```
'images.*' => 'file|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg',
```

and every time when I try to validate images, i have error like

```
The images.0 must be an image.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validate a base64 decoded image in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042731/validate-a-base64-decoded-image-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

I faced with this issue when I upgraded laravel framework from 5.5 to 5.6.
jpeg and jpg files had this issue in image validation. my validation was like this :

```
'img' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5000
```

I removed the image and just left the mime part and it worked! like this:

```
'img' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it two different methods.

We can use the first option:

```
$validate = $this->validate($request, [
    'description' => 'required',
    'image_path' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|required|max:20000'
]);
```

Or this second option :

```
$validate = $this->validate($request, [
    'description' => 'required',
    'image_path' => 'required|image'
]);
```

[List of mines type - images](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types)